# Condition for the existence of positive solution to cubic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, cubics

In a physics textbook I have encountered a cubic equation of the form:

$$Ax^3-Bx+C=0$$

The book states that there exists a positive solution $x>0$ to this equation if and only if the following inequality holds:

$$\sqrt{A}<\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\dfrac{B^{3/2}}{C}$$

I need some help figuring out the mathematical reasoning behind this assumption. Where does such an obscure-looking condition come from and how can I deduce it theoretically?

Comment: Given the negative sign in front of $B$ and the $\sqrt{A}$, there seems to be an implicit assumption that $A, B, C > 0$.

Comment: @ronno Yes, you are right, I forgot to mention that. These constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ are combinations of physical constants and are all strictly positive.

Comment: If $(A,B,C)=(1,3,2)$, then the equation has a solution $x=1$, but the inequality does not hold.

Comment: @mathlove Yes, the inequality should not be strict

Comment: As a slight alternative to the fine answer already given, let consider at first for $A,B,C>0$

$$q(x)=Ax^3-Bx=x(Ax^2-B)=0$$

which has three real roots at $x=0$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac A B}$ with negative minimum at $x=\sqrt{\frac A {3B}}$ from which we obtain the condition 

$$q\left(\sqrt{B/3A}\right)+C \le 0$$

which leads to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the polynomial by $f(x)$ and note that with $A, B, C > 0$, $f(0) = C > 0$ and $f(x) \sim Ax^3 > 0$ for large $x$. Therefore $f$ has a positive root iff it has a local minimum with $x_0 > 0$ and $f(x_0) \le 0$. So $f'(x_0) = 3Ax_0^2 - B = 0 \implies x_0 = \sqrt{B/3A}$. Then $f''(x_0) = 6Ax_0 > 0$ so it is automatically a local minimum, therefore the condition reduces to $f(\sqrt{B/3A}) \le 0$. Plugging in,
$$\frac{B^{3/2}}{3\sqrt{3A}} - \frac{B^{3/2}}{\sqrt{3A}} + C \le 0 \iff \sqrt{A} \le \frac{2B^{3/2}}{3\sqrt{3}C}.$$

Answer (score 3):

As $f(-\infty)=-\infty$ and $f(0)>0$, the polynomial has at least one negative root. As it is strictly concave on $(-\infty, 0)$, it cannot have three negative roots. Hence it has a positive root if and only if it has three real roots, that is to say if and only if its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) $4 A B^3-27 A^2 C^2$ is positive.